# Nifi putMongo upsert example

Tags: mongodb, apache-nifi

I'm struggling to find any examples that show how to use the upsert (or update for that matter) functionality in the putMongo NiFi processor.

I'd be grateful if someone could provide me with an example that I can then tailor to my own needs.

Specifically, given a flowfile containing a single JSON document, pull a single value from the document, filtering on that value, then upserting using a subset of the other available attributes and fields in the document.

What I'd love to do is similar to a SQL merge where an insert could follow one path and an update can follow another but I don't think the functionality allows that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> pull a single value from the document

The `update query key` parameter should do the job for you. By default, it uses `_id`, but you can specify a different key to use for finding a document to update. Additionally, you can specify a query using the `update query` configuration parameter.